# How can I correct this integer overflow behavior on an old GNU/Linux box?

Tags: c, integer-overflow

I have some software written in C that has worked fine for me on every system that I've tested it on, until now. One of our sysadmins has installed it on our cluster and some weird behavior has emerged.

In the program, I'm creating a DBM database with Kyoto Cabinet, though on this box the process fails before the db is created. The program takes command-line arguments to specify the size of the memory-map and the number of buckets used by the KC library. It appends these values to the file name in accordance with the documentation for `kcdbopen`. i.e., if the user passed `--mmap-size=1024 --num-buckets=256` for a db file called `foo.kch`, then a string `foo.kch#msiz=1024#bnum=256` is constructed and passed to `kcdbopen`.

As I said, this normally works fine. However, on this particular machine, the process will fail with an error that the memory could not be allocated. Plus, some debug text shows that the file that it tried to create starts with some garbage characters and the msiz and bnum numbers have overflowed to be something huge:

```
Failed to open database �!�u�foo.kch#msiz=249821240256#bnum=4199616: Cannot allocate memory
```

I'm using `argp_parse` to parse the command-line arguments. The relevant parts of that code are:

```
struct arguments
{
  char *args[1];
  unsigned long int mmap_size;
  unsigned long int num_buckets;
};

static error_t
parse_opt (int key, char *arg, struct argp_state *state)
{
  struct arguments *arguments = state->input;

  switch (key)
    {
    case 'm':
      arguments->mmap_size = arg ? atol (arg) : 1024;
      break;

    case 'b':
      arguments->num_buckets = arg ? atol (arg) : 100;
      break;

    case ARGP_KEY_ARG:
      if (state->arg_num >= 1)
        argp_usage (state);
      arguments->args[state->arg_num] = arg;
      break;
...<snip>....
```

I tried to be extra (overly?) cautious in building the filename string:

```
void *
zdb_create (char *dbfile, unsigned long int mmap_size, unsigned long int num_buckets,
            bool verbose)
{
...<snip>...
  char mmap_str[32];
  char buckets_str[32];
  char db_str[512];
  if (strlen (dbfile) > sizeof (db_str) - sizeof (buckets_str) - sizeof (mmap_str))
    error (EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "Filename too long");
  strncat (db_str, dbfile, strlen (dbfile));
  snprintf (mmap_str, sizeof(mmap_str), "#msiz=%lu", mmap_size);
  if (strlen (dbfile) + strlen (mmap_str) < sizeof (db_str))
    strncat (db_str, mmap_str, 32);
  else
    error (EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "Filename too long");
  snprintf (buckets_str, sizeof(buckets_str), "#bnum=%lu", num_buckets);
  if (strlen (dbfile) + strlen (mmap_str) < sizeof (db_str))
    strncat (db_str, buckets_str, 32);
  else
    error (EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "Filename too long");
  db = zdb_open (db_str, ZDB_CREATOR, false);
...<snip>...
```

So, I've just learned that there is a `strtoul` function, which might be the source of the problem; `atol` only converts to a standard `long` and not an `unsigned long`. However, I want to be 100% sure that I fix the problem before I go and bother the sysadmin again to try reinstalling (unfortunately, it's impossible for me to test it on my own, AFAICT). What is the most likely source of this overflow behavior? Are the integers overflowing and the garbage characters at the start of the string related? Why would this work on most systems except this one?

The system is using Linux 2.6.18, gcc 4.1.2 and, well, it's hard to tell which version of libc...version 2.3.x according to the `info` page for it. I've only tested on more recent systems, such as Linux 2.6.32 / gcc 4.4.3 / libc 2.8 and Linux 3.9.8 / gcc 4.8.1 / libc 2.17.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you stepped through this in a debugger on the platform in question?

Comment: Not yet because there's no debugger installed and said sysadmin is now gone until Tuesday...*le sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is problematic:

```
  char db_str[512]; // not initialized!
  if (strlen (dbfile) > sizeof (db_str) - sizeof (buckets_str) - sizeof (mmap_str))
    error (EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "Filename too long");
  strncat (db_str, dbfile, strlen (dbfile)); // adding to an uninitialized string!
```

You want to initialize db_str like this:

```
  char db_str[512] = "";
```

Comment: Ouch...yes, that's a problem. Thanks... :/ I'm still relatively new to C, as you can see.

Comment: Does `snprintf` also require the dest string to be initialized? The man page doesn't seem to indicate it.

Comment: @BrandonInvergo: No, any existing data in the destination string of `snprintf` is never read, so it doesn't have to be initialized.

Comment: OK, it's reasonable to believe that this is the source of the garbage characters at least. And it's probably the use of `atol` instead of `strtoul` that is the source of the integer overflows.

Comment: @BrandonInvergo: Note that valgrind would have caught this problem.

Comment: thanks for the tip; I haven't yet learned to use Valgrind. Clearly I need to make that a priority!

Comment: `char db_str[512] = "";` initialize all the array elements to `0` which is more than what is required. `char db_str[512]; db_str = '\0';` will initialize only the first one.

Comment: @BrandonInvergo " it's probably the use of atol instead of strtoul" -- No, that's not likely. You need to post the code that does the allocation that fails.

Comment: @JimBalter, what allocation do you mean? It's all there: the strings are converted to unsigned longs via `atoi` and stored in the `arguments` structure, then they are passed directly to that `zdb_create` function and are only used to construct the `db_str` string. There is nothing else in the code that deals with them.

Comment: @BrandonInvergo "the process will fail with an error that the memory could not be allocated" -- zdb_open probably failed because db_str is malformed; it has nothing to do with atol.

Comment: @JimBalter: `zdb_open` is just passing the string on to the Kyoto Cabinet `kcdbopen`. [Here is the whole file](http://invergo.net/paste/zdb.c-2013-07-04-0d6fc.html). Lines 24-47 are the ones included in my original question and lines 60-82 are where the database is opened. I think the process fails because it tries to allocate a huge amount of memory for the mmap when the `mmap-size` integer overflows (note that I specify 1024 bytes but I get 249821240256 bytes due to the overflow).

Comment: @BrandonInvergo You don't seem to understand the notion of overflow. 1024 will not become 249821240256 due to overflow, nor will atol misparse it.

Comment: You're right, I was using the term incorrectly. I do understand integer overflow (large numbers "wrapping around" to zero or to a negative number depending on signed/unsigned); for some reason the term came to my head in formulating this post and it just stuck there, despite being incorrect...I couldn't think of a more appropriate term. Anyway, I haven't figured out whether you are suggesting a solution or just correcting my mistakes. I won't be able to test until tomorrow whether the solution pointed out in this answer fixes everything, so I'm still open to further suggestions.